# Update model from list of viewmodels

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

View is something like this (I dynamically add and remove documents, Guids written here are DocumentIdentifier member of ViewModel):

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="DocumentViewModels.Index" value="8796c4e8-2262-46c0-bacc-8ffb6678b62a" />
    <input type="text" name="DocumentViewModels[8796c4e8-2262-46c0-bacc-8ffb6678b62a].Document.Name" />
    <input type="text" name="DocumentViewModels[8796c4e8-2262-46c0-bacc-8ffb6678b62a].Document.Type" />
<div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="DocumentViewModels.Index" value="3f2810c6-e338-4a6a-aa64-54b162303aab" />
    <input type="text" name="DocumentViewModels[3f2810c6-e338-4a6a-aa64-54b162303aab].Document.Name" />
    <input type="text" name="DocumentViewModels[3f2810c6-e338-4a6a-aa64-54b162303aab].Document.Type" />
<div>
```

I have viewmodel like this:

```
public class DocumentViewModel
{
    public Document Document {get;set;}
    public List<Attachments> {get;set;}
    public Guid DocumentIdentifier {get;set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult PostDocuments(List<DocumentViewModel> documentViewModels)
{
    // I successfully save newly added documents in database
    // Then I delete documents from database that are not in documentViewModels any more (because I dynamically add and delete them)
    // Then I find documents that are on form and in database too and I want to update them
    List<Document> matchedDocumentsFromDatabase = SynchronizeDocuments(documentViewModels.Select(x => x.Document));
    // Here i'm stuck. I want to write something like this:
    UpdateModel(matchedDocumentsFromDatabase, "DocumentViewModels");
    context.SaveChanges();
    // return something;
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use prefix as following.

```
public ActionResult PostDocuments(List<DocumentViewModel> documentViewModels)
{
    // I successfully save newly added documents in database
    // Then I delete documents from database that are not in documentViewModels any more (because I dynamically add and delete them)
    // Then I find documents that are on form and in database too and I want to update them
    var matchedDocumentsFromDatabase = SynchronizeDocuments(documentViewModels.Select(x => x.Document));
    // Here i'm stuck. I want to write something like this:
    string prefix = "";
    foreach(var item in matchedDocumentsFromDatabase)
    {
       prefix = string.Format("DocumentViewModels[{0}]",item.DocumentIdentifier .ToString());
       UpdateModel(item, prefix);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
    // return something;
}
```

hope this could help.

Comment: The guid written in View is not id of the document. See update

Comment: I need guids there to differentiate newly added documents (in case of id, they all would have id=0)

Comment: the DocumentIdentifier is associated with your view model anyway.isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is, ok, I'll try your solution, thanks, but no. look, prefix = string.Format("DocumentViewModels[{0}]",item.Id.ToString()); I can't do like this

Comment: Item does not have DocumentIdentifier any more

Comment: Oh!!how you have defined SynchronizeDocuments?

Comment: It's the method of generic repository, it accepts list of models and compares it to models in database and add/deletes them as neccessary. Returns elements that have same id as in db

Comment: did you'r scenario covers both insert and update or only update?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20385/discussion-between-karaxuna-and-behnam-esmaili)